# NestJS + class-validator, why errors array is empty?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I have this class:

```js
class SomeDto {
  @ArrayMaxSize(100)
  @Type(() => NestedDto)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  nested: NestedDto[];
}
```

and i use validation pipe as:

```js
@Body(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) { nested }: NestedDto,
```

It does the validation right, but i got an empty array of errors every time.

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "error": []
}
```

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - please share `NestedDto` to understand its validators.

Secondly I think the problem is that you use `NestedDto` instead of `SomeDto` in the body.

```js
@Body(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) { nested }: SomeDto // <- Not NestedDto.
```

In this case I'm getting correct errors about the array size.